# jquery validate user has entered text into 1 of 2 textboxes

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I am struggling to find an answer to this, if it can be done?

I have a login form that contains 3 textboxes: UserID, Post code, Date of Birth

The user id is fine I can add a required attribute to validate, but I was wanting to validate that they had also entered data into 1 of the other 2 textboxes, so either post code or date of birth.  I don't want to use asp.net custom validators as they are a pain, and was hoping that this could be done in html5/jQuery.  These textboxes are on a .net user control, so not sure if that is an issue as I have had trouble with it finding the form if i use something like... $("#form1").validate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to use ClientID of server controls for accessing them in javascript. You can bind javascript on click event of submit button and perform any validation.

```
$('#<%= submitButton.ClientID %>').click(function (){    
  textBox1Value =  $('#<%= textBox1.ClientID %>').val();
  textBox2Value =  $('#<%= textBox2.ClientID %>').val();
  //do validation on both textboxes here

  if(!conditionFormValidated)  //To prevent submit if form validation fail
     return false;
});
```

Comment: This put me on the right path, can't post the answer yet as i am too new apparently.

Answer (score 0):

You should check all three fields values in the textboxes. That should be checked on form submit. If two of them exist then you should re-initialize your validate method and invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, validating that 1 of 2 textboxes on a wizard control has a value.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  Button btn = (Button)Wizard.FindControl("StartNavigationTemplateContainerID").FindControl("StartNextButton");
  string script = "$(\"#" + btn.ClientID + "\").click(function () { if (($(\"#" + PostCode.ClientID + "\").val() == \"\" && $(\"#" + textDob.ClientID + "\").val() == \"\") || ($(\"#" + ClientId.ClientID + "\").val() == \"\" && $.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) < 10)) { $.jGrowl(\"<p style='padding: 3px; color: #fff;'>Please enter your Client ID and either a <em>Post code</em> or <em>Date of birth</em></p>\"); return false; }  });";
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "ValidateLogin", script, true);
}
```